# NodeJS, ExpressJS, Stripe - Error: Parse Error - on payment

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, stripe-payments

[image: Error]

- **Works fine on**: Windows (Windows 10, Node v13.10.1, NPM 6.14.4)
- **Error on**: Linux (Ubuntu 18.04, Node v12.16.2, NPM 6.14.4)

This happens when I pay for something using the Linux web server using Stripe live keys, or test keys.
It works fine when I use test keys, on my local Windows PC.

```
router.post('/stripe-webhook', async(req, res) => {
  try {
    // TODO: add better validation
    if (!req.headers['stripe-signature']) return;

    const id = req.body.data.object.metadata.id;
    if (req.body.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
      await giveUserPlus(id);
      return res.json({ success: true });
    }
    res.json({ received: true });
  } catch (error) { res.status(400).send(error); } 
});
```

[image: Live Test]

https://github.com/theADAMJR/2PG/blob/master/api/routes/api-routes.ts

Comment: ```console.log(req.headers)``` or debug, to find what is the value of headers and what to be.

Comment: Updated post to show req body on purchase.

Comment: Install same version of node on linux then check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix**: I changed the NodeJS version to fix it.